# alternative for .appendChild function

Tags: jquery

I am using the appendChild function for a project that I am working on.

This function is used within jQuery UI tabs however each time the tab is clicked the content inside the tabs is duplicated.

I really don't want the content to duplicated and I have tried everything to resolve the issue.

I hope you someone can help.

Many thanks!

jQuery

```
    function loadXMLDocTues()
    {
    xml = loadXMLDoc("./xml/tuesday.xml");
    xsl = loadXMLDoc("./xml/tv_guide.xsl");
    // code for IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
      {
      ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
      document.getElementById("tabs-2").innerHTML = ex;
      }
    // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
      {
      xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
      resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
      document.getElementById("tabs-2").appendChild(resultDocument);
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="loadXMLDocMon()">Monday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="loadXMLDocTues()">Tuesday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="loadXMLDocWed()">Wednesday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-4" onclick="loadXMLDocThurs()">Thursday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-5" onclick="loadXMLDocFri()">Friday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-6" onclick="loadXMLDocSat()">Saturday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-7" onclick="loadXMLDocSun()">Sunday</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div id="tabs-1">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-1 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-2">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-2 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-3">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-3 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-4">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-4 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-5">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-5 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-6">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-6 DIV-->

                <div id="tabs-7">
                </div>
                <!--CLOSING TABS-7 DIV-->
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

appendChild does exactly what the name implies and appends.
if you want to replace, which is what you want judging by your IE specific code then you need to use innerHTML

document.getElementById("tabs-2").innerHTML=resultDocument;

better yet, since you are using jQuery you can do this:

$("#tabs-2").html(resultDocument);

Comment: Hi, Thank you for getting back to me. Im quite new to everything and followed a tutorial for the code above. I tried your suggestion, however when I change it the content in the tabs disappears.

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: I have just added it, Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you sure you used $("#tabs-2").html(resultDocument)? and not mistakenly did $("#tabs").html(resultDocument)? Also, this can can be done much better. You can have one LoadXMLDoc function and pass it the day and the tab, instead of writing 7 of them.

Comment: Yes I tried using document.getElementById("tabs-1").innerHTML=resultDocument; however it won't load the content in to the tabs. I have tried everything and the code i am using is the only way the xml table displays. I just don't want to keep duplicating each time i press a tab.

Answer (score 0):

You're using innerHTML for the IE condition, is there a reason you're not using it for the Chrome / Firefox/Opera condition?

```
document.getElementById("tabs-2").innerHTML = resultDocument;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for getting back to me. Im quite new to everything and followed a tutorial for the code above. I tried your suggestion, however when I change it the content in the tabs disappears.